Thematic structure of verb and preposition
I am just wondering what would be the theta roles for the verbs and preposition phrases for this sentence "The coach genuinely believes the striker to be a big star." so far this is what i think it is, but not 100% certain [CP[[experiencer] The coach [VP [experiencer] genuinely believes] [CP Agent<∅> the striker to be a big star]]. My main issue is the embedded clause. I am struggling between this being the agent with no theme or just being a proposition as it is the thematic relation assigned to the clause.

Where's the preposition in that sentence?

Apologies there is no preposition- the main focus is on the predicates (verbs) and arguments (participants)

The thematic roles in a clause depend on the predicate. Your main predicate is the verb "believe". Its subject, the believer, is broadly called an experiencer, more specifically sometimes a "cognizer" (Van Valin), to distinguish it from subjects of perception and emotion within the broader category of experiencer. The object of "believe" is an abstract entity, usually "theme" applies as the wastebasket category.
Your embedded clause is a copula construction. Nothing very interesting can be said about these from the point of view of thematic roles. A role is defined as the set of entailments from the predicate for a participant, but the copula only entails identity of the descriptions. The subject is definitely not an agent, for this would presuppose an action taking place. In Dowty's classic paper on thematic roles (1991), copula verbs are not even mentioned, and the difference between the two arguments of the copula, if there is one, is ascribed to "perspective" not to lexical meaning or thematic roles (p. 566). The complement of a copula is not even a participant, but denotes a property.
In sum, talk about thematic roles has its limitations. The syntactic notions of argument, complement, etc. are more general and not all of them have content in terms of roles.
